# starting java executable from batch file yields error "Java Virtual Machine Launcher Could not find main class"

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

**Hi Stackers!** 
I have a vendor's java application that I want to start from a batch file in window 2007. 
The app boots fine from the shortcut, but it needs to kick off from a batch file. 
My command looks like this when I run it out of the .exe directory:
**start javaw.exe -param1 -param2 -param3 com.blah.blah.blah** 
But yeilds the following error: 
**"Java Virtual Machine Launcher Could not find the main class. Program will exit"**
The application icon is appearing when this error is thrown, so the application is attempting to start.
**Also** there's a "Start in:" parameter in the shortcut that I don't know how to pass to the start command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vendor Directory\Vendor Subdirectory\" & when this is removed from the icon properties then I get the same error. 
Also tried svcutil and java commands but these commands yielded similar results...
**Any help with this issues is greatly appreciated - Thanks!**

Comment: decompile the shortcut?

Comment: precede your `start` command with a `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Vendor Directory\Vendor Subdirectory` ? Current dir should be the same as where your .jar is located (unless you specify otherwise) or the root of a class folder in case if it's not packed into archive.

Comment: starting out of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vendor Directory\Vendor Subdirectory\" yields Database Connection Failed - An unexpected application error occured: Could not reach the database for the System Control value: application, log_ui_exceptions.

Comment: that sound like the next problem so the one related to 'no class found' seems to be resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Well part of the issues was syntax!**
Had to use procmon to figure that out. 
But when I sent the command: 
**start "Vendor App Name" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vendor Directory\Vendor Subdirectory\javaRt\bin\javaw.exe" -Param1 -Param1 -Param3  com.blah.blah** 
out of the directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Vendor Directory\Vendor Subdirectory\ it fired right up!
 
**Thanks to everyones help & they folks who built procmon for helping me figure this out! :-)**

Answer (score 1):

If JAVA is added to your class path simply go to the directory first where exe file from vendor exist. Your batch file will look like this:

```
    cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vendor Directory\Vendor Subdirectory"
    start javaw.exe -param1 -param2 -param3 com.blah.blah.blah
```

Comment: starting out of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vendor Directory\Vendor Subdirectory\" yields Database Connection Failed - An unexpected application error occured: Could not reach the database for the System Control value: application, log_ui_exceptions. KevinDTimm - how do I decompile a shortcut?